# Hierarchy query sum at each level

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table structure. I would like to get sum at each level from TAB2.

TAB1 stores hierarchy in level columns.

```
TAB1
----- -----  ---- ----
KEY   L1     L2   L3
---- -----  ----- ----
A     A
B     A     B
C     A     B     C
D     A     B     D

TAB2
-----
KEY   TC 
----  ----
A      10
B      11
C      6
D      12
X      11

Expected Output:

KEY  SUM
---- ----
A    39
B    29
C    6
D    12
X    11
```

Here is SQLFiddle Link: [LINK TO FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/619c57)

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please provide the desired output for this data, as it is not clear what you mean with *sum at each level*. I think of at least 3 interpretations of that.

Comment: Adding to trincot's comment - don't just provide the desired output, explain in English (no code!) HOW that output is to be derived.

Comment: Oh  - I think I get it now. In the last row of your sample input, in column L3, did you mean to write D, not C? Also, do you have the data as in TAB1, not in a normalized table with "parent" and "child" (in just two columns)?

Comment: I have added to SQL Fiddle

Comment: Your question is tagged with Oracle and SQL Server, your fiddle is marked as MySql. Which DBMS are you actually using?? I can't begin to come up with the logic for those desired values. A = 10. How does that become 39?

Comment: @SeanLange `A = 10` has the descendants `B`, `C` and `D` in the hierarchy which have the values `11`, `6` and `12` respectively - so `A = 10+11+6+12 = 39`.

Comment: Oops i am using Oracle DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**

```
Create table TAB1 (pKey varchar2(10),level1 varchar2(10),level2 varchar2(10),level3 varchar2(10),level4 varchar2(10));
insert into TAB1(pKey,level1) values('A','A');
insert into TAB1(pKey,level1,level2) values('B','A','B');
insert into TAB1(pKey,level1,level2,level3) values('C','A','B','C');
insert into TAB1(pKey,level1,level2,level3) values('D','A','B','D');

Create table TAB2 (pKey varchar(10), tc integer);
insert into TAB2(pKey,tc) values('A',10);
insert into TAB2(pKey,tc) values('B',11);
insert into TAB2(pKey,tc) values('C',6);
insert into TAB2(pKey,tc) values('D',12);
insert into TAB2(pKey,tc) values('X',11);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t2.pKey,
       SUM( COALESCE( t4.TC, t2.tc ) ) AS tc
FROM   tab2 t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tab1 t1
       ON ( t2.pKey = t1.pKey )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tab1 t3
       ON (    t1.level1 = t3.level1
           AND ( t1.level2 IS NULL OR t1.level2 = t3.level2 )
           AND ( t1.level3 IS NULL OR t1.level3 = t3.level3 )
           AND ( t1.level4 IS NULL OR t1.level4 = t3.level4 ) )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       tab2 t4
       ON ( t3.pKey = t4.pKey )
GROUP BY t2.pKey;
```

**Output**:

```
PKEY               TC
---------- ----------
D                  12 
A                  39 
B                  29 
C                   6 
X                  11
```

Answer (score 1):

In the solution provided below (including the input data as factored subqueries), first I show how to use `unpivot` and additional operations to normalize `tab1` (the result is the factored subquery `n` for "`n`ormalized"). Then, if you had the data in normal form, the output could be obtained by a direct application of standard hierarchical querying as shown at the bottom of my code.

```
with 
     tab1 (key, L1, L2, L3) as (
       select 'A', 'A', null, null from dual union all
       select 'B', 'A', 'B' , null from dual union all
       select 'C', 'A', 'B' , 'C'  from dual union all
       select 'D', 'A', 'B' , 'D'  from dual
     ),
     tab2 (key, TC) as (
       select 'A', 10 from dual union all
       select 'B', 11 from dual union all
       select 'C',  6 from dual union all
       select 'D', 12 from dual union all
       select 'X', 11 from dual
     ),
     unpiv (key, l, ancestor) as (
       select key, to_number(substr(lv, 2)), ancestor from tab1
       unpivot (ancestor for lv in (L1, L2, L3))
     ),
     d (key, depth) as (
       select key, max(l)
       from   unpiv
       group by key
     ),
     n (child, parent, TC) as (
       select d.key, u.ancestor, tab2.TC
       from unpiv u 
            right outer join d 
              on u.key = d.key and u.l = d.depth - 1
            left outer join tab2
              on d.key =  tab2.key
     )
SELECT key, sum(TC) as sum_TC 
from (
   select connect_by_root child as key, TC
   from   n
   connect by prior child = parent
)
group by key
order by key;
```

Along the way, in `unpiv`, I already had all the parent-child relationships, so I could have joined that directly with `tab2` on `unpiv.key = tab2.key` and summed `TC` grouping by `ancestor` (similar to MT0's solution). Instead, I wanted to demonstrate two separate steps: (1) normalizing `tab1` and (2) how easy it is to use hierarchical queries on normalized tables.

**Output**:

```
KEY     SUM_TC
--- ----------
A           39
B           29
C            6
D           12
```